# Unaligned memory access: is it defined behavior or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, memory-alignment, memory-access

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char* c = new char('a');
    char ac[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    unsigned long long int* u = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long int*>(c);
    unsigned long long int* uc = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long int*>(&ac[3]);
    *u = 42;
    *uc = 42;
    std::cout<<*u<<" "<<*uc<<std::endl;
}
```

Is this considered as a valid code, or is it memory leak/undefined behaviour?
I am asking, because through:

```
*u = 42;
*uc = 42;
```

we are accessing bytes that should not be reachable by the program (I guess).

Comment: Look for a non-standard keyword supported by your compiler, something resembling `__packed` or `__unaligned`.

Comment: You are modifying memory you shouldn't have access to. Thus I don't think it matters whether it is on a word boundary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*u = 42;` causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule. `*u` is an lvalue of type `unsigned long long`, and the strict aliasing rule says that this may only be used to access objects (that already exist) and have type `long long` or `unsigned long long`. However your code uses it to access an array of `char`.

C++ doesn't have a specific rule for aligned accesses (unlike C). This is because in C++ it's not possible to write code that would perform an unaligned access without causing undefined behaviour due to one of the following things:

- violating the strict aliasing rule.
- accessing memory where no object exists.
- supplying an unaligned address to placement-new.