How to access unaligned data in rust without copies
I have a code base that loads a huge binary data file in memory and, without additional allocations, map it to proper data types (u32, f64, f32...). The problem is that this file is packed, and a recent change in rust 1.78 broke this.
I know that both C++ and rust declare accessing unaligned data an "undefined" behaviour, but, given the fact I'm using unsafe, why should I not be able to do it?
fn main() {
    let arr: &[u8] = &[100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190];
    let f1 = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(arr.as_ptr() as *const f32, 2) };
    let f2 = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(arr[1..].as_ptr() as *const f32, 2) };
    println!("F1: {}, {} F2: {}, {}", f1[0], f1[1], f2[0], f2[1]);
}

int main() {
    uint8_t arr[] = {100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190};
    float *f1 = (float*)arr;
    float *f2 = (float*)&arr[1];
    std::cerr << "f1:" << std::dec << f1[0] << ", " << f1[1] << " f2:" << f2[0] << ", " << f2[1] << std::endl;
}

The results are the same and the code works properly both on arm64 and x86_64 IF I compile it with any version of GCC / CLANG (c++) or rust (... up to 1.77).
If I update rust to 1.78 the code fails with the error:
thread 'main' panicked at library/core/src/panicking.rs:156:5:
unsafe precondition(s) violated: slice::from_raw_parts requires the pointer to be aligned and non-null, and the total size of the slice not to exceed `isize::MAX`
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread caused non-unwinding panic. aborting.
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV

There is a zero-copy way to avoid this? The source file(s) are up to 1GB of size and having to copy the data in the arrays is not an option since they should be parsed as fast as possible... it's really annoying to have a rust version broke something that worked (even in an undefined behaviour scenario, that is anyway under control with unit tests in all the supported archs).

@wohlstad Is it not? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126257/what-does-the-standard-say-about-unaligned-memory-access.

@wohlstad You can do that by memcpy'ing, but that's no longer unaligned.

@ChayimFriedman I agree. Anyway the OP claimed that accessing unaligned memory is UB in C++, and that given that they use the unsafe keyword (which is not in C++ anyway) they should be able to. I think this is not a correct statement in general (which was all the intention behind my comment).

float *f1 = (float*)arr; float *f2 = (float*)&arr[1]; This doesn't look like a real (serialized) data. What do you want to achieve with the overlapped objects? Please show a more life and not fictional example.

Given that some hardware will explode in your face with an unaligned access, what do you hope should happen here?

"given the fact I'm using unsafe, why should I not be able to do it?" unsafe means "trust me I know what I'm doing even if you can't check it". You're literally trying to do something you're not allowed to.

Unaligned pointer access is allowed both on x86, x86_64 and arm64, it's trapped in arm32 if you do not use __packed, but if you know your target architecture you should be able to do it.
To answer @273k, the example is minimal, but if you think that in the array the first value is a byte and from byte 1 there is the float (since it's serialized from a packed binary file) it's something easy to do (and very common) in c/c++.

It’s wrong to rely on unaligned pointer accesses even in C and C++. “But my arch—” doesn’t matter, compilers can assume unaligned pointers do not exist even when the target architecture supports them.

https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointer-accesses/

The C++ code is UB. It violates all primary guidelines. Use of built-in C array is discouraged; std::array should be used instead. uint8_t is not portable std C++; std::uint8_t must be used. addressof operator (unary &) is dangerous and must be avoided in C++. Pointers are not recommended to newbies. C style casting is bad practice. Type punning through reinterpret_cast is no approved. You've just broken every C++ rule. Continue this path and you'll end up with too many undetectable runtime issues . Or learn to stick with the rules and stay away from runtime problems.

@ChayimFriedman I realized my comments were somewhat   incorrect and removed them. +1 for your answer.

unsafe is not a free ticket to cause UB. It only means you are responsible to not cause UB instead of the compiler.
To be clear, even before 1.77.0 you were not allowed to do this. It is just that up to this version the compiler, within its permission and as a possible outcome of the UB you invoked, compiled the program successfully (and maybe it did what you wanted, or maybe not, or maybe it depended on the environment variables and the position of you in the universe), and since 1.77.0 it does another possible outcome of UB, that is panicking at runtime. Any other outcome is also possible, including formatting your hard drive.
References cannot be unaligned. This is a rule you cannot break, ever. If you need unaligned data, you will have to stay in raw pointers land and use read_unaligned() to read the bytes. You don't have to copy, you can just move the pointer around and only read when you need the values.
An alternative will be to use a #[repr(C, packed)] struct representing your data format, possibly with a library such as zerocopy.

@PasserBy There are ways to make this actually happen, although admittedly I will be quite surprised to hear this has happened in practice. But this is a common way to emphasis the danger of UB, which many people tend to ignore for some reason.

The point is that my code used to convert everything in slices with the correct types, and so with a single unsafe {} line I was able to keep everything else idiomatic rust, using read_unaligned() I will have to spread the "unsafe" logic all around the code base...

@gabry Indeed. But your code was incorrect and worked by luck (or lack of luck). Maybe it even had bugs you didn't know of. You may have better luck with zerocopy.

Alternatively, use just #[repr(C)] on the structures and wrap primitives like #[repr(packed)] struct unaligned_f32(f32);
